# Tensorflow low accuracy when training with multi GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Is it normal that I get lower accuracy when training on multi GPU? For example, when I train on single GPU with *n* batch size, I got 63% accuracy. However, when I train with 4 GPUs with *n* batch size for each GPU, I got only 58% accuracy. Both cases were trained with 100 epochs

I guess the averaging of gradient somehow makes it difficult for the optimizer. Anybody experienced the same thing ?

Comment: Are you using `set_random_seed`? Did you observe this issue multiple times?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I configured the training manually

Comment: The difference in accuracy might be random and not related to using one or more GPUs. If you use `set_random_seed` the training sessions should yield identical results every time.

Comment: No, I repeated the training 2 times for each case. The same thing happened, always low accuracy with multi GPU

Comment: I'd also be interested to hear about this. I have noticed an accuracy drop using an identical model with the same data and hyperparameters between using 3 GPUs and 4 GPUs.

Comment: @GhostRider Yes! I experienced the same thing. My guess is that the gradient not "so nice" after averaging. Instead of using a batch size of 128 for each GPU, I reduced the batch size to 64 for each GPU, I saw a slight improvement in accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the model was trained after 100 epochs, you can infer the model and find the accuracy on CPU itself because it is not computationally heavy. But if you want to observe the accuracy while training, then it can be hard to find accuracy from each GPUs and averaging, which might not tell how good is the model that is being trained.

Comment: I somehow figured out the reason. Instead of using n batch size for each GPU, I used  batch_size = ( batch_size / num_gpus). So says, you have batch_size of 128 and want to use 4 GPUs, you would use a batch size of 32 for each GPU instead of 128. The batch size did have a significant effect on the accuracy